# Add items to Sharepoint Online list using Web Service provided by sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services, list-item

I want to add a new item to a sharepoint list using /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx web service.

I have used the following code

```
        SharePointListService.Lists currentListService = new SharePointListService.Lists();
        currentListService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement batch_element = doc.CreateElement("Batch");
        string item = "<Method ID=\"1\" Cmd=\"New\">" + "<Field Name=\"ID\">New</Field>" + "<Field Name=\"Title\">This is a test</Field>" + "</Method>";
        batch_element.InnerXml = item;
        currentListService.UpdateListItems("Resources", batch_element);
```

This is giving me an Access Denied Error. Am I doing something wrong in code or is there any other work around to add list item to Sharepoint Online list using /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx webservice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got my issue resolved. We can directly authenticate Sharepoint Online site by using the below code

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL))
{
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(siteUserName, passWord);
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(web);
}
```

Here we can use client side object model to authenticate the Sharepoint online site.

Read more about it here:

[Authenticating .NET Client Object Model](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/01/authenticating-net-client-object-model.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can authorize towards #sharepoint-online via NetworkCredentials - try using claims instead:

[How to do active authentication to Office 365 and SharePoint Online](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Dag, I have worked out the problem using client side object model.